# How to get the step name description using pytest-bdd?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, bdd, gherkin, pytest-bdd

I want to get this step description name "capture user logout option navigated screen" within the function. But not able to get it

@when(parsers.parse('capture "{user}" logout option navigated screen'), converters=CONVERTERS)
def step_capture_login_option_navigated_screen(context, user, request):
step_name = request.node.name

I have tried request.node.name but it's giving the Scenario name, but I need exact step name

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.